# Works of mathematician François Viète

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, reference-request

I'm searching for a book or an online copy of complete works of the mathematician [François Viète](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Vi%C3%A8te), preferably in English.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Complete... I'm not sure about it. You can see : François Viète, [The Analytic Art](https://books.google.it/books?id=omHqrYBzMpAC&printsec=frontcover) (1591).

Comment: You can search into [Gallica's archive](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58230969.r).

Comment: See also Francisci Vietae, [Opera mathematica](https://books.google.it/books?id=fTze9nSv0ucC&printsec=frontcover) (1646).